# Python: how to convert the first dimension of a netcdf file to a dataframe?

Tags: python, netcdf

I am quite new with `NetCDF` files. I am trying to analyze a dataset that contains global information of land use from 1899 to 2019. I would like to select a year and convert the information into a dataframe.

This is what I am doing

```
import xarray as xr  
dnc = xr.open_dataset(fn)
dnc
```

[image]

How can I get the data fro the year 1965 and convert to a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Converting an xarray dataset to dataframe is fairly straightforward, as there is a built-in method:

```
df = ds.to_dataframe()
```